# Redux Form crashes app without errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

When loading a redux form (code from https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui example) it crashes the app with no errors in the console. Here is what the form looks like:

```
import {Component} from 'react'
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem'
import { RadioButton } from 'material-ui/RadioButton'
import {
  Checkbox,
  RadioButtonGroup,
  SelectField,
  TextField,
  Toggle
} from 'redux-form-material-ui'

class MyForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Field name="username" component={TextField} hintText="Street"/>

        <Field name="plan" component={SelectField} hintText="Select a plan">
          <MenuItem value="monthly" primaryText="Monthly"/>
          <MenuItem value="yearly" primaryText="Yearly"/>
          <MenuItem value="lifetime" primaryText="Lifetime"/>
        </Field>

        <Field name="agreeToTerms" component={Checkbox} label="Agree to terms?"/>

        <Field name="receiveEmails" component={Toggle} label="Please spam me!"/>

        <Field name="bestFramework" component={RadioButtonGroup}>
          <RadioButton value="react" label="React"/>
          <RadioButton value="angular" label="Angular"/>
          <RadioButton value="ember" label="Ember"/>
        </Field>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

// Decorate with redux-form 
MyForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm'
})(MyForm)

export default MyForm
```

I'm then rendering this COMP with  in the parent. I have also included "formReducer" in the combineReducers function.

Comment: AFAIK JSX is still looking for React in the scope, so you want to ```import React, { Component } from 'react';``` in your first line

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this didn't help.

Comment: Actually it caused the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null"

Comment: Well, [the example works](http://erikras.github.io/redux-form-material-ui/). Have you run [the exact code in the repo](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui/tree/master/example)?

Comment: Yes, nothing seems to work